# Adding a cookie if referral query string exists in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've using the code below to save a cookie if there is a query string named `referrer` in the URL.

It was working but I now get an error:

```
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "referrer"
```

This points to the `if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer']) && $_GET['referrer'])` line, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
add_action('init', 'set_cookie_based_on_url_parameter_referrer');
function set_cookie_based_on_url_parameter_referrer()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer']) && $_GET['referrer']) {
        $cookie_expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
        $_SESSION['referrer'] = $_GET['referrer'];
        setcookie('referrer', $_SESSION['referrer'], $cookie_expire, '/', '.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }
}
```

Is this correct to wrap in an if statement? Sorry!!

```
add_action('init', 'set_cookie_based_on_url_parameter_referrer');
function set_cookie_based_on_url_parameter_referrer()
{
    if (isset($_GET['referrer'])) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer']) && $_GET['referrer']) {
            $cookie_expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
            $_SESSION['referrer'] = $_GET['referrer'];
            setcookie('referrer', $_SESSION['referrer'], $cookie_expire, '/', '.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if exists with `isset($_GET['referrer'])`

Comment: Ah ok, so do I wrap it in another if? like this:

`add_action('init', 'set_cookie_based_on_url_parameter_referrer');
function set_cookie_based_on_url_parameter_referrer()
{
    if (isset($_GET['referrer'])) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer']) && $_GET['referrer']) {
            $cookie_expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
            $_SESSION['referrer'] = $_GET['referrer'];
            setcookie('referrer', $_SESSION['referrer'], $cookie_expire, '/', '.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        }
    }
}`